# Root Page is not part of the Navigation.NavigationStack collection

Tags: c#, ios, navigation, xamarin.forms

When my app starts, I so some logic in my `AppDelegate` and assign the `MainPage` a page based on the results of that logic.

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
{
    global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init ();

    // .....

    if(authorizationStatus == PhotoLibraryAuthorizationStatus.Authorized)
    {
        bokehApp.SetStartupView(serviceLocator.GetService<AlbumsPage>());
    }
    else
    {
        bokehApp.SetStartupView(serviceLocator.GetService<StartupPage>());
    }
}
```

In my app.cs, I assign the `MainPage` the given view from the `AppDelegate`

```
public class App : Xamarin.Forms.Application
{
    public void SetStartupView(ContentPage page)
    {
        this.MainPage = new NavigationPage(page);
    }
}
```

In this instance, I am passing `StartupPage` into the `SetStartupView(Page)` method. When the user does something, I navigate to the `AlbumsPage`.

```
this.Navigation.PushAsync(new AlbumPage());
```

When I do this, the `AlbumPage` is created and navigated to; it's `Navigation.NavigationStack` collection only contains itself, not the Page that it just navigated from. What I want to do, is prevent a call to `this.Navigation.PopAsync()` navigating back to the `StartupPage`, which is what currently happens.

Initially I was going to just run a loop and pop the original Page off, and then remove all of the remaining pages, in this case `StartupPage`.

```
// Grab the current page, as it is about to become our new Root.
var navigatedPages = this.Navigation.NavigationStack.ToList();
Page newRootPage = navigatedPages.Last();

// Dont include the current item on the stack in the removal.
navigatedPages.Remove(newRootPage);

while(navigatedPages.Count > 0)
{
    Page currentPage = navigatedPages.Last();
    this.Navigation.RemovePage(currentPage);
}
```

However, when I look, the `Navigation.NavigationStack` collection *only* contains the `AlbumsPage`. Yet, calling `this.Navigation.PopAsync()` navigates back to the `StartupPage`.

What do I need to do in order to reset this navigation stack, so that popping will not navigate back to the initial page?

#### Update

When I navigate, I've been able to use this:

```
App.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(viewModelPage);
```

as suggested by @Daniel but this prevents the animation from taking place. I have also tried

```
await App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(fooPage);
App.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(fooPage);
```

When I do this, I see the new page transitioned to, but once the await call on `PushAsync` finishes, and the `MainPage` is replaced, the Page disappears and I'm left with an empty screen.

I really don't want to lose the animations during transitioning from my setup Page to the actual app.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue. This mostly came down to my lack of understanding how the NavigationPage worked. It would seem that each Page is given their own Navigation stack. As I navigated between Pages and examined their `NavigationStack` collections, they always just had one item in them.

I then started looking at `App.Current.MainPage.Navigation` and discovered that it actually had the entire stack (both `StartupPage` and `FooPage`). I was able to then grab the `StartupPage` prior to pushing the `FooPage` onto the navigation stack, and then removing the `StartupPage` once the navigation to `FooPage` was completed. This essentially let me reset the root page, while keeping the transition animation between the views.

```
Page originalRootPage = App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.NavigationStack.Last();
await App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new FooPage());
App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.RemovePage(originalRootPage);
```

I'll mark this as answered when the time-period has expired and i'm allowed to.

Comment: So simple and yet so hard to find! Thanks so much.

Answer (score 5):

I think what you're looking for is setting:

`App.Current.MainPage`

to a new `NavigationPage`. It replaces main page of application.

Comment: This works fine for hard view changes. I can't navigate to the next Page, then replace the old MainPage with the new root. For some reason it wipes out the view all together and leaves me with an empty page when the navigation transition completes. So it looks like the only way to do this is to straight replace `App.Current.MainPage`, which isn't animated. Can you animate the transition between pages, or am I just stuck with a unanimated view change? Are there other ways of doing that are better, and don't require replacing the MainPage to prevent navigating back to a setup page?

Answer (score 1):

This is fix my problem.

```
    protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
    {
        foreach (Page page in Navigation.ModalStack)
        {
            page.Navigation.PopModalAsync();
        }

        return true;
    }
```